# In Cucumber : How to show the Total scenario executed count properly in the console output

Tags: spring, gradle, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am running Cucumber Junit test in JAVA using Spring Boot Project and I am getting my console output as below

```
Tests passed :30 of 30 tests
```

Note : Actually I am running only 10 scenarios with each scenario 2 steps but the output shows as (10 + 10*2 = 30 passed) . This number is not making scenes .  It should show me 10 of 10 tests

In build.gradle file ,

My cucumber version used  = '1.2.5'

```
List cucumber = ["info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:${cucumberVersion}",
                 "info.cukes:cucumber-core:${cucumberVersion}",
                 "info.cukes:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}",
                 "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:${cucumberVersion}",
                 "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:${cucumberVersion}"]
```

Is there any way i can give a meaningful output instead of adding the steps count again with the actual scenarios count ?

Comment: Upgrade your Cucumber.

Comment: Does cucumber in info.cukes is same as io.cucumber ? is there any preference ?

Comment: Its the modern version. You may want to start over with the tutorial. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/